# Changing borders and linestyles around various ranges in vba

Tags: vba, excel, border

[image: my table now]

[[image: what I want my table to look like[2]]

I am trying to get a proper border around my table, but everytime I try to make it around certain ranges based on color, it comes out as dotted lines. I want solid lines, but nothing I seem to do to the linestyle works. I also don't want the black vertical lines within the red boxes, but it was the only way to get the line solid not dashed. The first picture I attached is what mine looks like, and the second is what I want mine to look like. Here is the code I've been using as well:

```
Sub borders()
'
' borders and colors
'

'
'B column = blue

   range("B2:B46, D2:D6").Select
   Selection.BorderAround
    With Selection.Interior

        .Color = 6108951

    End With

    'C column = gray

   range("C2:C6").Select
   With Selection.borders(xlLeft)
    .Weight = xlThin
   End With
   With Selection.borders(xlRight)
   .Weight = xlThin
   End With

   With Selection.Interior
    .Color = 12632256
    End With


   range("C7:C46").Select
   Selection.borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   With Selection.Interior
    .Color = 12632256
    End With

    'thin columns = gray
   range("E2:E46, I2:I46, M2:M46, Q2:Q46, U2:U46, Y2:Y46, AC2:AC46, AG2:AG46, AK2:AK46, AO2:AO46, AS2:AS46").Select
    Selection.BorderAround (xlThin)
   Selection.borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   With Selection.Interior
    .Color = 11711154
    End With

  'rows gray
    range("B21, B36, B43, B46").Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Color = 12632256
   End With

'categories gray

range("D7:D45").Select
Selection.borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

 With Selection.Interior
 .Color = 15395562
  End With

   'red rows
   range("C21:AS21, C36:AS36, C43:AS43, C46:AS46").Select
    Selection.BorderAround (xlThin)
   Selection.borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   'Selection.Border -Style: Solid
       With Selection.Interior
        .Color = 128
     End With


     'outside thick border

range("B2:AX46").Select
   Selection.BorderAround , Weight:=xlThick


   'border around trigger, weight, limit
   range("AU5:AW20").Select
    Selection.borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

    range("AU5:AW6").Select
    Selection.borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.BorderAround (xlThin)




   End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try making it all one call, so

```
'thin columns = gray
   range("E2:E46, I2:I46, M2:M46, Q2:Q46, U2:U46, Y2:Y46, AC2:AC46, AG2:AG46, AK2:AK46, AO2:AO46, AS2:AS46").Select
    Selection.BorderAround Weight:=xlThin, LineStyle:= xlContinuous
   With Selection.Interior
    .Color = 11711154
    End With
```

Comment: okay that worked thank you! One more question though: any ideas on how to get the red line to overlap the gray columns so they're black outline doesn't show in the red?

Comment: @beks123 I think the best method would be to just remove the left and right borders `Line(xlLeft/xlRight).Visible = False` for all the cells in that range, except for the ones on the very ends.  Do that after everything has run though (to ensure that you dont remove the lines before they are added)